# dot indexing not supported while using struct gets a different error

Tags: matlab, indexing, data-structures, struct

Ppl
I am trying to loop over a set of variables of a class and assigning a different value for each.
what I am saying is this

there is a calss def called T
I am accessing certain variables in T using dot indexing

```
classdef T 

properties 
   wheels = 2.3;
```

now I am trying to do this

```
wheelV=[ 1 2 3];
for i=1:5 
 T.Wheels = wheelV(i);
end
```

However this will lead to the error "unable to assign value cause dot indexing is not supported for this variable type" Now I can use a struct in this means

```
T.wheels=struct('r',wheelV(i));
```

But this wont work as the variable T.Wheels will be used in another class where it needs to be multiplied and hence I get a different error that you can't multiply.

is there a way to index this T.Wheels without having to declare it as a struct.

Using Widnows 10, 64x
Matlab R2021b

Comment: If `T` is a class, you must create a value of that class to assign to: `t = T; t.wheels = 1;`.

Comment: yes I did create a value but i want to loop and give it a new value. However I managed to solve it, the problem is the call of the class was out of the for loop, thats why it can't index through its methods, after having it inside it worked. can someone throw me a bone to the logic beyond why class calling must be inside the for loop, I want to understand the logic.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "call of the class". All I know is that you have a class called T, then `T.wheels` (or `T.Wheels` as in the other snippet) is illegal unless `wheels` is a static property, and even in that case you cannot write to it. Since nobody posted an answer yet, feel free to update your question by [edit]ing it, to clarify this latest question.